# Mapping undefined properties to optional ones

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a mapped type that makes properties that can be undefined optional.

More specifically, I have a type like this one:

```
interface Input {
  foo: string;
  bar: string | undefined;
  baz: number | undefined;
}
```

and I want to use a Mapped Type to turn it into this type:

```
interface Output {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
  baz?: number;
}
```

I can only find examples that make ALL properties optional, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution (using TS 4.1):

```
interface Input {
    foo: string;
    bar: string | undefined;
    baz: number | undefined;
}

type UndefinedToOptional = { 
  [K in keyof Input as undefined extends Input[K] ? K : never]?: Input[K] 
}

type T1 = Omit<Input, keyof UndefinedToOptional> & UndefinedToOptional
/* 
{
    foo: string;
    bar?: string | undefined;
    baz?: number | undefined;
}
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Input {
  foo: string;
  bar: string | undefined;
  baz: number | undefined;
}

// test
const a1: Input = { foo: '' } // error
const a2: Input = { foo: '', bar: '', baz: undefined } // good

type UndefinedProps<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? P : never
}[keyof T];

type RemoveUndefined<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P] ? NonNullable<T[P]> : never;
}

type Output = 
  Omit<Input, UndefinedProps<Input>> // { foo: string }
  & Partial<RemoveUndefined<Pick<Input, UndefinedProps<Input>>>>; // { bar: string; baz: string; }

// test
const b1: Output = { foo: '' }; // good
const b2: Output = { foo: '', bar: '', baz: undefined } // good
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyyMA9qQFzIDOYUoA5gNxHIBGcUVt9IDyAH2RYQAEwgxQEUS2IcAXlRBYAtm2iDhYiVJkEAvgQIB6Y8ki0CCUiFrI4ARirpsuALz4S5KgHIfyfWRTZGgoUigrGzs4ACZnTBxkDzwvSmQ-ABp2Tl8fLIUqEXFJEGkAozAATwwUAFVtEukABTCMagAeABUAPiT8VgBtJuRQZABrCErSGGROgF1Cht0QgA9IMWpZobnkAH5kYaUIADdoAwGJqZn5lgIqmuQAJQgVUlP64t0u3uTB4dHLtNZgstJ9SqJVutRJtOts9sgAHI2BFYAA2qLgbFREC6216R1OUBYhju1RQAHkcK4+uSVMAwO0XDgsh8dOCWqQ2oyEmBur0AGQHThgYBwVHtZ6vd5LcHtJrABBjbmuFky5qtDpM3l87q3YIWMCRWy4NhOZCUsDU5KpXIBFjWY3sOLmqmJa1kNKZbJcdJ5bKKUFssqGIA)